# Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory ( (SSL) encryption. Error: Signature algorithm mismatch".)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am getting the following error message when connecting to a MSSQL Server 2008 DB:

> Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Signature algorithm mismatch".)

I am using `sqljdbc4.0.jar` and my connection string is as follows:

```
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" maxActive="10" maxIdle="4"
    name="sql2008" username="sa" password="pwd" type="javax.sql.DataSource"     
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.111:1435;databaseName=sampledb;"
```

OS: windows8 (64bit);
Java Editor: Netbeans 7.2.1(64 bit)

Please help me to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i found the solution by google it.

create the certificate for the SQLSERVER by using the following cmd:

makecert -r -pe -n "CN=SQLServer2008" -b 01/01/2012 -e 01/01/2040 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -ss my -sr localMachine -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12

and register the self-signed certificate

and assignthe certificate to sqlserver.

For more detailed info visit: http://goralsoft.com/blog/?p=99